# Как создать фильтр и менять определённый текст в C?

Tags: c

Здравствуйте!

Пишу программу, которая работает с файлом txt, она оттуда должна удалять по определённому шаблону текст, как работать с файлами от и до, я знаю, а как сделать, задать такой шаблон, чтобы удалялось, заменялось то, что надо (текст)?

Спасибо.

PS Если я непонятно выразился, то скажите.

Comment: Что-нибудь вроде [Регулярных выражений](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Регулярные_выражения)?

Comment: Все зависит от того, что нужно сделать с текстом, какая обработка требуется. Может, все довольно просто и можно обойтись без регулярных выражений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для подобный задач хорошо подходят регулярные выражения. Они не входят в стандарт С, поэтому надо подключать внешние библиотеки. Пример на основе POSIX regexp:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    regex_t regex;
    int result;
    char buffer[256];

    /* Компилировать, ... - искомый шаблон */
    result = regcomp(&regex, "...", 0);
    if (!result) {
        /* Выполнить, ... тестовая строка */
        result = regexec(&regex, "...", 0, NULL, 0);
        if (!result) {
            /* Найдено совпадение: что-то сделать */
        }
        /* Очистить */
        regfree(&regex);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, литературу в которой можно глубоко изучить библиотеку regex.h(Правильно я понял, она создаёт регулярное выражение?)?

Comment: Справка есть на сайте GNU: [Regular Expression Matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html) на английском, вполне возможно где-то и на русском можно найти.

Comment: Краткий, но содержательный обзор regexp для С можно найти в книге Джонсон, Троан "Разработка приложений в среде Linux".

Comment: Часто проще использовать fnmatch(), она использует набор метасимволов и правила сопоставления с регулярным выражением такие же, как sh.